# How can I retrieve a user using a query string from drupal using REST?

Tags: web-services, drupal, drupal-6, httpwebrequest

### What I'd like

I want to be able to reset a users password without emailing them. I also need to do this via REST (it's for a kiosk system).

So I need to:

1. Get user with a specific username
2. Reset the password of that user

Try as I might, I can't get the user with a username.

### The problem

After I've logged in using the admin user via REST I do:

`GET on http://mydomain.com/rest/user?name=user`.

According to REST documentation, this should get the user with name `user`.

I get a 200 response, but **nothing is returned in the body**.

### What I've Tried

**Get node from ID**

Once I've logged in as admin, I can do:

GET on http://mydomain.com/rest/user/1

This works, returning the details of user 1 in the response. But I need to search for a user by username.

**Different GETs**

```
GET on http://mydomain.com/rest/user/admin
GET on http://mydomain.com/rest/user/account/name/admin
GET on http://mydomain.com/rest/user?account[name]=admin
GET on http://mydomain.com/rest/user?uid=1
GET on http://mydomain.com/rest/user/retrieve?uid=1
GET on http://mydomain.com/rest/user?account[uid]=1
```

All these fail.

**Nodes instead of users**

GET on `http://mydomain.com/rest/node/1` works, but `http://mydomain.com/rest/node?nid=1` gives me a 200 response with nothing in the body.

**List of all users**

`GET on http://mydomain.com/rest/user/` doesn't show a list of all users either. I get a 200 with empty body again.

### Further Details

- I'm working with a Drupal 6.22 install.
- I've installed the services module (3.0 RC1) and REST Server (2.0 beta 1).
- I've got the session authentication module installed.
- I've tried the above with the session authentication switched on and with it off.
- I've enabled all node resources and user resources for the REST endpoint I've set up.
- I've tried the above with and without clean URLs and nothing seems to make a difference.

### Question

How do I get a user with a specific username? What am I doing wrong?

### Update

I've uninstalled then reinstalled Services module, I've done the same with the REST server. I've also rolled back my version of CTools to the latest recommended one. I've added a brand new service in case it was corrupted. Nothing I do works. Frustrating!

### Update 2

I've found the problem, but would like a more permanent solution. It turns out it was an error because of table naming. See my current accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. It's an error/bug with the Services module in the setup I have.

From the `services.module` file

```
449  // Now implode that array into an actual WHERE clause.
450  $where = !empty($where) ? ' WHERE '. implode(' AND ', $where) : '';

451  // Run through db_rewrite_sql to make sure proper access checks are applied.
    // **** Error logged for this next line ****
452  $sql = "SELECT $fields FROM {$table} $where ORDER BY $order"; // <-- Error was logged for this line
453  $sql = db_rewrite_sql($sql);
454  $result = db_query_range($sql, $parameters, $page * 20, 20);
455  return $result;
```

The error

```
  Table '<REDACTED>_drup1.users' doesn't exist query: SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0, 20 in /<REDACTED>/sites/all/modules/services/services.module on line 455.
```

The users table in my installation is called `drup_users`. When I change line 452 to

```
452  $sql = "SELECT $fields FROM drup_{$table} $where ORDER BY $order";
```

It works. I'd be interested in knowing how I can have a more permanent solution. I ran update.php several times and it didn't fix this.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Should I download the most recent patch in the comments do you think, or just wait until the module itself is updated? I'm working with a site that's due to go into production in the next few weeks.

Comment: I would put the patch in sites/all/patches (or something similar) and apply it until an update comes out, but it should be fixed before the update goes out.

Answer (score 3):

Im sorry this is so frustrating for you. Im the maintainer for services module and were really working on the documentation but I thought I would answer here to just get you moving along.

The reason you are not getting any of the data you want is because the parameters you are passing are wrong.

If you look at user_resource.inc index is defined as follows

```
      'index' => array(
    'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/user_resource'),
    'callback' => '_user_resource_index',
    'args' => array(
      array(
        'name' => 'page',
        'optional' => TRUE,
        'type' => 'int',
        'description' => 'The zero-based index of the page to get, defaults to 0.',
        'default value' => 0,
        'source' => array('param' => 'page'),
      ),
      array(
        'name' => 'fields',
        'optional' => TRUE,
        'type' => 'string',
        'description' => 'The fields to get.',
        'default value' => '*',
        'source' => array('param' => 'fields'),
      ),
      array(
        'name' => 'parameters',
        'optional' => TRUE,
        'type' => 'array',
        'description' => 'Parameters',
        'default value' => array(),
        'source' => array('param' => 'parameters'),
      ),
    ),
    'access arguments' => array('access user profiles'),
    'access arguments append' => FALSE,
  ),
```

Notice the third argument, parameters.
You can do all sorts of fun stuff with the index query as long as it is turned on, but what you havnt tried is ?parameters[name]=user Example below

When I make a request to http://test/api/user?parameters[name]=gdsfgsdfgsdfg&fields=name,uid
I get returned

```
[
 {
  "name":"gdsfgsdfgsdfg",
  "uid":"36",
  "uri":"http:\/\/test\/api\/user\/36"
 }
]
```

Notice i also added some fields, uid and name. Obviously these are optional but it shows you the power of the index query. The same applies to nodes.

I hope this helps.
[image: Fetcher]

Comment: Wow, Kyle. Thanks for your excellent example and detailed answer. None of this is why it wasn't working for me though. It was because when querying the users, the services module as looking at the wrong table name and throwing an error - which I ignored, like a plonker. Once I changed the Services code, it worked like a dream. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
GET on http://mydomain.com/rest/user?parameters[name]=admin
```

This worked for me in Drupal7.  Not sure if it'll be the same for 6.  But I also had no issues with getting the index of all users using GET on http://mydomain.com/rest/user/

Comment: Nope. It gives me exactly the same thing - a 200 response with blank body. :(

Comment: @John Gallagher -- Have you enabled all the CRUD+Index functionalities for the User resource as described in the **Endpoint settings** section of http://drupal.org/node/783722 ??  I know in Drupal 7, I can choose only to provide Retrieval service without providing the Index service.

Comment: @John Gallagher -- Getting a list of users seems pretty straight forward so if that's not working, perhaps you can post some of your client code to see if anyone else has any ideas?

Comment: I haven't even put this into the client code yet - I'm just testing it out using REST Console within Chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/faceofpmfclkengnkgkgjkcibdbhemoc - to generate my requests and examine my responses. I can't make it much simpler - there's really no extra detail to my test requests that I haven't got in my question.

Comment: Nevertheless, the question clearly needs some more detail, so I'll add an update tomorrow detailing this exchange. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: @John Gallagher -- If you haven't yet done so, enable debug mode in your service instance. Also, are there any errors logged?

Comment: @nmc Thanks. I've found the problem now. Yeah, annoyingly there were errors that were being logged and like a total plonker I ignored them. I didn't think they had anything to do with my requests... ahem... *not working*. Once I fixed these errors, it worked like a charm. See my update.